# Kiln Version 0.5.3 Voting Problem

Tags: node, voting, kiln

I am running a node using Kiln Version 0.5.3 running on Ubuntu.

I am baking using a Ledger device and I am attempting to vote using Tezos Wallet App Version 2.0.1

When I select Vote on Kiln, I show my Ledger device recognized and I see “Respond to the Prompt on your Ledger device...” but I do not see a prompt on the Ledger, then I see on Kiln “The Ledger prompt was rejected or timed out.  Please try again.”

I am in the Tezos Wallet App when attempting.  I am able to use this app to authorize other transactions (sending XTZ).

I’d really like to vote, just not sure what to do as I have attempted multiple times and have also re-installed the apps and re-paired the Ledger to Kiln.

Any advice would be much appreciated.  Also, command line solutions are beyond my pay grade...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bug. Remove the baker, vote, add the baker again.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your baker went inactive when you were switching between Kiln and Bakechain. You can use a block explorer such as tzscan to confirm if you went inactive.

Once your rolls are captured in a snapshot you should regain voting rights a few cycles later.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this issue may have to do with the fact that I stopped using Bakechain for a few weeks before starting back up with Kiln so I am waiting on my turn to start endorsing and baking again.  It would make sense that my voting rights are on hold too.